# Зачем стоит запускать Xcode с зажатым shift?

Tags: xcode, mac

Видел, что можно запускать Xcode с зажатой клавишей shift.

Поясните, зачем это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нажатие Shift при открытии программ предотвращает восстановление последней сессии, то есть открытие окон и файлов, которые были открыты в последний раз. [Цитата из документации:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204005)

> To temporarily prevent an app from re-opening its documents and windows, hold the Shift key while you open the app.

Эта фича свойственна не только для Xcode, но и для других программы Apple, и не только.